# Index my Hard drive into solr

Tags: java, search, solr, system, solrj

I want to index my system each files and folders information into solr. Is there any handler in solr to do it?
I can index any file using data import handler using below command

**curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?ext.idx.attr=true\&ext.def.fl=text&commit=true" -F "myfile=@tmp1.txt"**

But i want to index my whole system into solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be done via http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FileListEntityProcessor, you could specify

> fileName :(required) A regex pattern to identify files
>
> baseDir : (required) The Base directory (absolute path)
>
> recursive : Recursive listing or not. Default is 'false'

If you specify fileName as '*', baseDir as '/', recursive as 'true' it looks like it will enumerate all files.